# How to prepare tasty tea on induction cooktop?

Tags: induction

I used to preapre tea on gas stove. For two, my measurements were, 2.5 tea spoon of Tata tea, 1 glass water, 5 spoons of sugar. The measurements arent that important as they are in relation to spoons I have. I used to keep it on gas for 8 min with least flame and it used to turn yummy. I came with this formula over long time of experimentation.Recently, I bought [Prestige PIC 16.0 plus Induction Cooktop](https://www.flipkart.com/prestige-pic-16-0-plus-induction-cooktop/p/itme3cyxcddty24f?pid=ICTE3CYXDVHGGYH3) and since then for a week I am not able to prepare tea well. First of all, even on least temprature within couple of minutes the tea boils down quickly and starts spilling. So I guess tea and sugar doesnt get enough time to mix well and tea turns not so tasty. I am not able to figure it out how can I prepare tasty tea on this induction cooktop as I am alredy operating at least temprature, that is 65 degrees Celcius.

1. This is 1900 W cooktop. I am guessing if 1200 W cooktop would have given lower temprature. Is it so? Should I return this cooktop and try some other?
2. You can view control panel of this cook top [here](https://postimg.cc/p5d2zpYs). So it has eight modes: pressure cooker, curry, dosa/chapati, idly, deep fry, heat milk, keep warm and saute. I guess each option is nothing much but different combination of temperature and timer. I usually put it on saute and reduce temperature to 65 degrees. Still it never worked. I also tried pausing heating for some minutes and starting it again while continuously stirring it. It improved but still not satisfactory.
3. I also observed induction heat comes waves. It boils tea for some seconds, then stops for some seconds and then again boils and then stops again. Is it normal? Is it the reason for not so great tea?
4. I am now doubtful if I can prepare good food on induction cooktop similar to gas stove. For example, my chapatis on gas stove looks like [this](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9wRckHxyblI/XSvUQSvnx2I/AAAAAAAAZ88/m_SmmSOA3O4DdMAKek82hnpO3ppOTGY8ACEwYBhgL/s640/20190713_101147.jpg). Now I am wondering whether I will able to prepare same on induction cooktop as it gets hot quickly. Is it possible?

Comment: What sort of pot are you using? Does it have a very heavy base, that will retain heat?

Comment: its steel pot..

Comment: yes but **Does it have a very heavy base, that will retain heat?**

Comment: if you were boiling your tea before (100ºC) and now you try to simmer it at 65 ºC you'll  definitely not get the same result... Your problem doesn't seem to be the equipment, but the way you operate it. There are plenty of chefs that use induction cooktops with great results.

Comment: @Luciano I did not use to boil it fully. I used to keep it on stove with "lowest flame" and turn the stove off in 10 min max. Till that time, boiling used to just start with some bubbles appearing, not fully boiling with a lot of bubbles and spilling. But with induction at 65 degrees, it gets boiled fully and spill in just 3-4 minutes.

Comment: @ChrisH [these are pots](https://i.postimg.cc/KYcx5GCQ/image.png) I tried till now.

Comment: I think that instructions like "I keep the kettle at temperature X for Y minutes" would be easily replicable than trying to reproduce the "lower heat" of the gas stove on the induction cooktop. The 65 degrees your induction cooktop says looks like a stage in the rising temperature curve and isn't kept for much as it starts boiling in short. This means that the X figure above should be measured with a thermometer in the kettle and not trusting that a knob on 65 takes everything on the burner at 65.

Comment: @DavidP not able to get u exactly. Are you suggesting anything to try out?

Comment: Also I checked many youtube videos ([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFL8KlS3U1g),[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbefZx4QBi8)) of preparing tea on induction oven. In those also, tea starts boiling in 3-4 minutes. So I guess this is typical with induction cooktops. But I also believe it should need more time to get mixed well. Also whatever is possible on gas stove should also be possible with induction cooktop ideally. So I am somewhat directionless about how can I imitate same taste with induction cooktop.

Comment: Just saying that to compare two appliances (your old gas and new induction cooktop) you need a _third_ tool, namely a thermometer together with a stopwatch, as 65 degrees on one of the two cooktops does not mean much. How could the manufacturer claim that that intensity would keep a pot of unknown material full of food we don't know to 65 degrees, and in how much time? I also have problems in mantaining low temperatures for hours on my burner and what I do is using a cast iron pot (heat retention) and take it on and off the heat. This is annoying for a 4 hrs stew but for tea can be worth?

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying, my working hypothesis is that you are overheating your tea.

My first suggestion would be to forget all the modes of your cooktop (Pressure cook, etc.) and also the "degrees" scale. I have always found that a degree scale on an induction cooktop does more harm than good, since it has little relation to the actual temperature of your food. It is very obvious in your case: when a mixture of milk and water boils, it is at 100C, not at 65C.

So what you should do is to manually select the 120 W setting and try cooking with it. If it also requires you to select some mode from the lower row, then my guess would be that saute is indeed a good choice.

If using the lowest setting (the 120 W) doesn't work, there are two and a half other ways to make it cook slower. One is to make a larger amount of tea at once. The other is to place the pan farther away from the coil. A thin wooden chopping board might be enough for a test, but it might char with prolonged use, so if you are happy with that solution, you could try a pizza stone or a bathroom tile for permanent use. Don't use anything that can melt or catch fire, or anything that's made of metal. It is still best to combine that with using the 120 W setting - if you were to use something thick and a higher setting, you would be wasting energy.

The "half" way is to move the cooking vessel such that its bottom is only partially on the stove. It might not work at all, if the sensor notices that parts of the coil are uncovered, and if it works, it is inefficient and makes for badly cooked food. For me, it isn't worth doing it, but I am listing it here for completeness.

The observation that the heat comes in waves is perfectly normal, that's how induction stoves work (the technical term is "time modulation"). Without that, they would be much, much hotter (all the heat all the time) and the food would burn instantly.